# How do I declare field variable of tested class using apache velocity?

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-velocity

I'm trying to setup intellij idea code template for `JUnit4 Test Class` so that when I create the test it will also generate a field variable in the test. Example :

```
public class FooTest {
    private Foo foo;
    ...
}
```

The problem I'm having is using the `$CLASS_NAME` variable to set the field name with lower camel case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a toLowerCase() of first character. Sample below for reference.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} {
  ${BODY}
  #set($var_name = ${NAME})
  #set($var_name = $var_name.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + $var_name.substring(1))

  private ${CLASS_NAME} $var_name;
}
```

Comment: Your code produces `fooTest`. I've added the following to trim the `Test` part out.
    `#set($length = $var_name.length() - 4)`